# Routing post requests with a polymorphic comment table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have a user and goal table that associate with a polymorphic comment table. My question is what's the best way to setup my comments controller to differentiate between the two? I'm looking more for best practices more than an outright solution.

I'm just learning rails and still relatively new to development in general. I'm using an if statement to create the comment right now but I feel as though there is another way I'm not thinking of. I'm checking if params[:user_id] is nil in which case ill set comment type and redirect url accordingly. Is there a better solution?

Please forgive if more info is needed. This is one of the first posts I've made in regards to a problem I've run into. Let me know if I can provide anything else to help.

Comment: [this video](https://gorails.com/episodes/comments-with-polymorphic-associations) should give you a general idea of how to implement polymorphic associations

Comment: Thank you. That video helped alot